# Is there actually a best way to handle errors?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to provision a new stream analytics job using powershell script on azure, The following snippet is part of a script file which will add services to resource group.

sample code :

```
try{
    New-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsJob -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -File $template -Name $streamAnalyticsJobName -Force -ErrorAction Stop 
}catch{
    Write-Output $error[0] | Out-File -Append -FilePath $errLogFilePath

}
```

or

```
New-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsJob -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -File $template -Name $streamAnalyticsJobName -Force -ErrorVariable Errorvalue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Output Errorvalue | Out-File -Append -FilePath $errLogFilePath
```

what is recommended /best way to document errors in a log file for review.

Comment: What would you have the script do with an error? There is no objective "best" way to handle errors because different situations require different recovery actions. There is the global ErrorActionPreference variable which is the default behavior if no ErrorAction is provided. You can also use trap statements as global error handlers.

Comment: In both of your examples, you are not handling any errors.  You might as well ignore the try/catch block entirely and toss `-ErrorAction Stop` to the call and leave it at that.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It's slightly different. The first example essentially turns any terminating error into a non-terminating error. If it was in a script, the script would continue executing. It also outputs to the output stream instead of the error stream, which does not seem like a good idea in general.

Comment: @BaconBits Right, but in either case, they're not *handling* anything.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 In some cases, turning a terminating error into a non-terminating error *is* handling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your 1st command will also handle any *terminating* error issued by `New-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsJob`, thanks to use of `try` / `catch`.

  - Speaking generally, if the command had multiple inputs and issued *non-terminating* errors on a per-input basis - which means that processing would *continue* by default, even after a specific input causes a non-terminating error - your use of `-ErrorAction Stop` would actually *short-circuit* that and abort on encountering the *first* non-terminating error.
- In your 2nd command, if a *terminating* error were to occur, your use of `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` would *not* be effective and neither would be your attempt to capture that error via `-ErrorVariable` - in short: common parameter `-ErrorAction` only affects *non-terminating* errors.

By contrast, the `$ErrorActionPreference` *preference variable* - surprisingly<sup>[1]</sup> - *does* also affect how *terminating* errors are treated, so, as a general pattern, you could to the following, if your intent is:

- to *continue processing*, irrespective of whether errors occur and whether they are non-terminating or terminating.
- to let errors occur *silently*, and only *log them to a file*.

```
  # Silently ignore any subsequent errors, irrespective of severity, but
  # still record them in the automatic $Error collection.
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

  # Save the current count of errors stored in $Error.
  $errCountBefore = $Error.Count

  New-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsJob -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -File $template -Name $streamAnalyticsJobName -Force

  # If errors occurred, append them to a log.
  if ($Error.Count -gt $errCountBefore) {
     $Error[$errCountBefore..($Error.Count-1)] >> $errLogFilePath
  }
```

---

<sup>[1] For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's error handling and its pitfalls, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it @tuggo; I've just added a footnote with a link to a  comprehensive overview of PowerShell's error handling and its pitfalls.